# Why doesn't typescript warn about the return type in this function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function

For example, I have an onClick handler on a `<div>` tag. The handler should expect a return type of `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> | undefined` . But, I still can return a boolean value of false when `temp = false`. Got confused here why Typescript did not warn me about the return type

```
import React from 'react';

const Dummy= () => {
  const [temp, settemp] = React.useState(false)
  const [text, settext] = React.useState('Hi')

  const handler : React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> | undefined  = () =>{
    return temp && settext('bye')
    //return temp
    
  }
  return (
   <div onClick={handler}> Testing </div>
  );
};

export default Dummy;
```

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing the question to something like `Why doesn't typescript warn about the return type in this function?` as that is more accurate to what you (appear to be) asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling typescript that the `handler` variable is `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> | undefined`. Note that it is never actually undefined, as it is a const and is therefore only ever a function. You're not telling it what the function's return type is. These are two different things. The return type is either derived from what you return in the function, or you can explicitly declare it after the parameters, like this:

```
let sum = (x: number, y: number): number => {
    return x + y;
}
```